# Define array of structure within a structure in C++

Tags: c++, struct

I am trying to create a structure `Student` which contains q substructures named `Course`. Each `Course` is a structure with a credit and point `int` values.

How do I set up my `Student` structure to have an integer number of `Course` structures within it? Thanks

```
struct Student{
    int q;
    Course course[q];
};

struct Course{
    int credit;
    int point;
};
```

I tried this but VSC is telling me it is wrong.

Edit error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


struct Course{
    string name;
    int credit;
    int point;
};

typedef struct Student{
    vector<Course> courses;
};



int main() {

    Student student;

    system("cls");
    int input;
    int input2;
    string strinput;
    cout<<"--------------------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"                    GPA & CGPA Calculator (Developed by Ohid)             "<<endl;
    cout<<"--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"<<endl;
    cout<<"Set up the student!"<<endl;
    sub:
    cout<<"Add a course"<<endl;
    cout<<"Course name: ";
    cin>>strinput;
    cout<<"Course points: ";
    cin>>input;
    cout<<"Course credits ";
    cin>>input2;
    student.courses.push_back({strinput,input,input2});
    cout<<"Add another course (1/0)?: ";
    cin>>input;
    switch(input)
    {
        case 1:
            goto sub;
            break; 
        case 2:
            break;
    }
    
    int numCourses = student.courses.size();

    cout<<"--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"<<endl;
    cout<<"Student created with "<<student.q<<" courses!"<<endl;

    cout<<"--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"<<endl;
    cout<<"            MENU:"<<endl;
    cout<<"                   1. Calculate GPA (Grade Point Average)"<<endl;
    cout<<"                   2. Calculate CGPA (Cummulative Grade Point Average)"<<endl;
    cout<<"                   3. Method that is applied here for calclating GPA & CGPA"<<endl;
    cout<<"                   4. Exit Application"<<endl;
    cout<<"--------------------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    sub:
    cout<<"Enter your choice: ";
    cin>>input;

    switch(input)
    {
        case 1:
            cout<<"You chose calculate GPA";
            calculateGPA();
            break;
        case 2:
            cout<<"You chose calculate CGPA";
            calculateCGPA();
            break;
        case 3:
            cout<<"You chose method";
            method();
            break;
        case 4:
            cout<<"You chose to exit";
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            break;
        default:
            cout<<"You are stupid";
            goto sub;
            break;
    }
}



void calculateGPA()
{

}

void calculateCGPA()
{

}

void method()
{


}
```

Error text!
'Course': undeclared identifiercpp(C2065)
'std::vector': 'Course' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'cpp(C2923)
'std::vector': too few template argumentscpp(C2976)
class std::vector

Fixed std etc.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>




struct Course{
    std::string name;
    int credit;
    int point;
};

typedef struct Student{
    std::vector<Course> courses;
};



int main() {

    Student student;

    system("cls");
    int input;
    int input2;
    std::string strinput;
    std::cout<<"--------------------------------------------------------------------------"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"                    GPA & CGPA Calculator (Developed by Ohid)             "<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Set up the student!"<<std::endl;
    sub:
    std::cout<<"Add a course"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Course name: ";
    std::cin>>strinput;
    std::cout<<"Course points: ";
    std::cin>>input;
    std::cout<<"Course credits ";
    std::cin>>input2;
    student.courses.push_back({strinput,input,input2});
    std::cout<<"Add another course (1/0)?: ";
    std::cin>>input;
    switch(input)
    {
        case 1:
            goto sub;
            break; 
        case 2:
            break;
    }
    
    int numCourses = student.courses.size();

    std::cout<<"--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Student created with "<<numCourses<<" courses!"<<std::endl;

    std::cout<<"--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"            MENU:"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"                   1. Calculate GPA (Grade Point Average)"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"                   2. Calculate CGPA (Cummulative Grade Point Average)"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"                   3. Method that is applied here for calclating GPA & CGPA"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"                   4. Exit Application"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"--------------------------------------------------------------------------"<<std::endl;
    sub:
    std::cout<<"Enter your choice: ";
    std::cin>>input;

    switch(input)
    {
        case 1:
            std::cout<<"You chose calculate GPA";
            calculateGPA();
            break;
        case 2:
            std::cout<<"You chose calculate CGPA";
            calculateCGPA();
            break;
        case 3:
            std::cout<<"You chose method";
            method();
            break;
        case 4:
            std::cout<<"You chose to exit";
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            break;
        default:
            std::cout<<"You are stupid";
            goto sub;
            break;
    }
}



void calculateGPA()
{

}

void calculateCGPA()
{

}

void method()
{


}
```

Comment: Use `std::vector<Course> courses;`. You cannot use such a C array without a compile time constant as size, and anyway `std::vector` is recommeded over it in C++.

Comment: In C++, every declared array must have dimensions that are compile-time constants.  If you have a modest upper bound on the number of `Course`s any `Student` can have then you could declare that as the dimension of `Student.course`, and let `Student.q` indicate how many are used. But that's pretty hackish, because what you appear to be trying to do is exactly what `std::vector` is for.

Comment: Hi both, I have used std::vector thank you! I have an error which I have added in a edit

Comment: `struct Course` has to be above `struct Student` if you want to use the former in the latter. Also, what's up with `typedef`? You don't need it.

Comment: Please post the error message as copy-pasted text. See: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: Also a side note: [What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: @crankymidlifecrisis You must define `Course` **before** you use it. Just swap the order of the two structs

Comment: @wohlstad Added error text, sorry! And thanks will read that.

Comment: @john I tried that I still get the error

Comment: @crankymidlifecrisis Also now that you are using a vector you can remove `q`. A vector knows it's own size, you don't need to store the size in a separate variable.

Comment: @crankymidlifecrisis Well you forgot to save your file (or something).

Comment: @crankymidlifecrisis Maybe you forgot to `#include <vector>`

Comment: *"still get the error"* Please show the latest code and the exact error message. Don't omit the headers, and so on.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat have added

Comment: Works for me here: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/89WMET7Yr Are you sure this is the code you're compiling?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat sorry it didn't paste all the code, have pasted it all now

Comment: I get different errors, not the ones you have in the question: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rW6z3c1ba  And those are quite obvious, like `'q': is not a member of 'Student'`.

Comment: Oh forgot to remove q as just deleted it from the structure and haven't updated the below code yet

Comment: @crankymidlifecrisis You are also missing `#include <string>`. Please test compile the code before you post to be sure that it is behaving as you say it is.

Comment: std::string through namespace std

Comment: @crankymidlifecrisis `std::string` comes from the header file <string> nowhere else. Probably what is happening is that the file <iostream> is also including <string> but that's just your compiler, another compiler might not do the same, so if you use `std::string` you should `#include <string>` always.

Comment: Stop *`using namespace std;`*! That can drastically narrow errors.

Comment: Fixed all the std stuff, still not working

Comment: Do you still have the same error? If so, my guess is that you are not saving your changes, or you are not compiling the file you think you are compiling.

Comment: One more nitpick. C++ and not C: *`struct Student`* and not *`typedef struct Student`*.

Comment: What are the new errors?

Comment: "'Course': undeclared identifiercpp(C2065)
'std::vector': 'Course' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'cpp(C2923)
'std::vector': too few template argumentscpp(C2976)
class std::vector<Course>"

Comment: @crankymidlifecrisis As you can see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Y9aTvTsdb) your code still has some problems but not that one. You're doing something screwy when you try to build (no idea what) because the code above does not produce that error.

Comment: @john You're right. I restarted VSC and everything works. No idea what was happening

Comment: Glad it now works. @crankymidlifecrisis is to be commended for listening to what folks suggested, and interacting with them. He is a model of what new users at Stack Overflow (especially students) should be.